# MATLAB's gpuArray; insufficient compute capability

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I am running MATLAB R2011b on Ubuntu 12.04 on a 2 year old Macbook Pro. I would like to make use of the GPU capabilities of MATLAB. However, when I try, I find that my GPU does not seem to be powerful enough:

```
>> gpuArray(rand(10))
Error using gpuArray (line 28)
No device supporting CUDA was found.

>> gpuDevice
Warning: The device selected (device 1, "GeForce GT 330M") does not have sufficient compute
capability to be used. Compute capability 1.3 (or greater) is required, the selected device
has compute capability 1.2.
```

Does this mean I can never use MATLAB's GPU functions on my machine? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GT330m is compute capability 1.2](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)    MATLAB GPU support from mathworks requires compute capability 1.3 (or higher) as you've discovered.  I don't know what to say about "never".  That's a long time.   But [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/291689) indicates that [jacket](http://www.accelereyes.com/products/jacket) from accelereyes maybe an alternative and also gives the Mathworks perspective on the limitation to cc 1.3 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer and collection of links. Jacket is probably outside my budget for very casual academic use, but I will bear it in mind for the future. It is a shame that so many relatively new machines cannot use the full MATLAB functionality - a sentiment also expressed in the thread you link to!

Comment: @BillCheatham Jacket costs $350 for an academic.